# Why base64_encode() return null

Tags: php

I have a 22M docx file and want to encode it using base64_encode() function in php. But It always returns NULL value after running this function. Is there any limit file size or condition for this function. My code:

```
$handle = fopen($fullpathfile, "rb");
$imagestr = base64_encode(fread($handle, filesize($fullpathfile)));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: What does fread return? Do you 'know' it is the docx file, or have you actually tested it?

Comment: [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) never returns `null`. However, it returns `false` on failure.

Comment: 22M is large file, maybe you are getting "out of memory" somewhere.

Comment: @GolezTrol fread also return NULL. It is docx file

Comment: First save the contents of the file in another variable and echo that. Im guessing something is wrong there, because there is not alot to do wrong with `base64_encode()`

Comment: Do you actually need the whole Base64 encoded string at a time. You could process the file in chunks if that’s applicable.

Comment: @NguyenMinhTuan If fread returns null then it's not base64_encode that goed wrong, but reading the file. Check the results of `fopen` to see if it's a proper handle. Maybe the path is wrong or access to the file is denied. Alternatively, you could use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the file in one go, but still you would have to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$fh = fopen($fullpathfile, 'rb');


$cache = '';
$eof = false;

while (1) {

    if (!$eof) {
        if (!feof($fh)) {
            $row = fgets($fh, 4096);
        } else {
            $row = '';
            $eof = true;
        }
    }

    if ($cache !== '')
        $row = $cache.$row;
    elseif ($eof)
        break;

    $b64 = base64_encode($row);
    $put = '';

    if (strlen($b64) < 76) {
        if ($eof) {
            $put = $b64."\n";
            $cache = '';
        } else {
            $cache = $row;
        }

    } elseif (strlen($b64) > 76) {
        do {
            $put .= substr($b64, 0, 76)."\n";
            $b64 = substr($b64, 76);
        } while (strlen($b64) > 76);

        $cache = base64_decode($b64);

    } else {
        if (!$eof && $b64{75} == '=') {
            $cache = $row;
        } else {
            $put = $b64."\n";
            $cache = '';
        }
    }

    if ($put !== '') {
        echo $put;

    }
}


fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Please supply comments in the code to explain how this works :)